# can't display page in iFrame in windows Phone 8

Tags: iframe, windows-phone-8, cordova

In PhoneGap App under windows phone 8,
They Keep telling me this error even I delete all content except some paragraph.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved it by load external URL in iframe instead of read from under device and it is working.

Comment: Please, could you elaborate... We have the same problem... but it doesn't work in an iframe

Comment: did you allow this external url in config.xml of your app